# Python Shell returns ImportError: No module named 'ldap' exception

Tags: python, flask, import, ldap, python-ldap

i have installed `python-ldap` and `flask-ldap` on my centos machine.

when i try import ldap, **python 2.x** works good. but in **python 3.4** version it returns following exception:

```
ImportError: No module named 'ldap'
```

any other libraries am i need to install to use ldap in python 3.4 version?

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

**edit:**

i am trying to install libraries in python 3.4 version by following command:

```
python3.4 -m pip install python-ldap

python3.4 -m pip install Flask-LDAP
```

but i am getting following exception:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-qvn41t9w/python-ldap/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-zev4yfdk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-qvn41t9w/python-ldap/
```

Comment: For me, I installed and kept `pip2` and `pip3`, they are independent :-( I don't know if your pip is just a "pip2".

Comment: did you installed `ldap` for python 3 like this: `pip install ldap3` ???

Comment: Installing a module in Python 2.7 does not install it for Python 3.4. Installing a module in Python 3.6 also does not install it for Python 3.4. You need to look for the `pip` executable that corresponds to the installation you are working with and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install a module separately for every version of python you intend to use. If you installed it on python 2.7 it will not be installed on python 3.6. Even if you installed it on 3.6, it would not be installed on 3.7. You will have to separately install the module for every python version you intend to use it on.

It may help to read [this tutorial on pip troubleshooting](https://www.questionmark.com/content/questionmark-pip-reference-guide-troubleshooting) and [installing modules in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

resolved it by ensuring node is subscribed to repo first. Then searched for available modules: yum search python3 | grep ldap
installed preferred module: yum install -y python3-ldap.x86_64
NOTE: this is on RHEL8